# Video Stream / Hosting

Tags: video, video-streaming

Our client wants us to update their web application by adding video capabilities.
It's kind of like YouTube, but with accounts and video privacy. It should be able to stream videos, both live and recorded.

Instead of developing a custom application, we just decided to get a out of the box application. It can be open source, but we're willing to try out licensed offerings. Do you guys have any suggestions as to what we can use?

The web application is in .Net 2.0 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Yep - the easiest way to do this in all honesty is with the **Flash Media Server** - or a compatible piece of software. You can then use a Flash/Flex application to utilize the media itself. There are several similar packages to the FMS which are compatible, though I can't pull a name out of my head tonight (Google will help you.)

This is pretty standard and you'll find a wealth of tutorials to help you online.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out the Flash Media Server Developer edition.

Answer (score 0):

you could consider

http://www.kyte.com/

http://influxis.com/applications/

http://www.uvault.com/

thanks

Comment: Thanks. I'll go check on those links.

Answer (score 0):

To stream both live and recorded videos, [live video streaming](http://hioxindia.com/live-stream-hosting.php) with flash media server or wowza server would be the best option. These software brings out the streaming with multiple playback clients and devices too.

Answer (score 0):

Windows baed? Windows Media Services can do that for the last 15 years or so, part of the windows oeprating system anyway.